# What's the easiest way to draw a sphere at a certain coordinate with PyopenVR?

Tags: python, virtual-reality, openvr

No texture required, pure color is ok, radius also doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to draw the sphere in OpenGL for OpenVR (literally the same way it's done for C++ OpenVR apps) and submit those frames to the OpenVR compositor.

Also did you check the examples provided with `pyopenvr`? They have a pretty good [OpenGL example](https://github.com/cmbruns/pyopenvr/blob/PyOpenVR-1.16/src/samples/glfw/hellovr_glfw.py).